# Perfomance Comparision NHibernate and ADO.NET

Tags: performance, nhibernate, orm, fluent-nhibernate

I have evaluating the performance of NHibernate and ADO.NET. I have created a test application which has an Employee table with 75,000 records. When I try to get data using NHibernate it is very slow compare to ADO.NET, it’s about **290%** (approx.) slower.

The average performance of NHibenrnate to bind 75,000 records is **2535** milliseconds .
The average performance of ADO.net  to bind 75,000 records is **867**  milliseconds.

I can understand that NHibernate is a Wrapper to ADO.NET but you cannot pay the price of 300% for retrieval

We tried the optimization tips for NHibernate from Internet. Here are some

1. Use of Stateless Session
2. Use of Named Query
3. Session Flushing
4. Using Stored Procedure
5. Using Recompiled option

As per my experience time is getting consumed when building the objects in memory. Also the query which is getting fired from NHibernate and SQL in profiler has differences. Does not make any difference if executed again and again

Select ID, Name, DateOfJoin, DateOfBirth, DepartmentID, Status from Employee : **Duration 516**
Select this._ID as ID2_0_, this_.Name as Name2_0_, this_.DateOfJoin as DateOfJoin2_0_, this_.DateOfBirth as DateOfBirth2_0_, this_.DepartmentID as DepartmentID2_0_, this_.Status as Status2_0_ from dbo.Employee this_: **Duration 1538**

Kindly suggest any other mechanism for increasing the performance. What should be the ideal performance difference when using ORM?

Please find the code below….

```
//Employee Class
public class Employee
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime DateOfJoin { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public virtual string DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Status { get; set; }
}

//NHibernate Mapping
public EmployeeMap()
{            
    Table("Employee");
    Id(p => p.ID).GeneratedBy.Increment();
    Map(p => p. Name);
    Map(p => p. DateOfJoin);
    Map(p => p. DateOfBirth);
    Map(p => p. DepartmentID);
    Map(p => p. Status);                    
}
//Building Session Factory
public static ISessionFactory SessionFactory
    {
       get
        {
            if (_sessionFactory == null)
            {
                _sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
                .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("Connection")))
    .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Employee>())                    
                                  .BuildSessionFactory();
            }
            return _sessionFactory;
        }
    }

//Fetching data using CreateQuey
using (IStatelessSession session = SessionManager.SessionFactory.OpenStatelessSession())
{
  IList<Employee> lstEmployee = session.CreateCriteria< Employee >().List<Employee>();               
return lstEmployees.ToList<Employee>();
}

//Fetching data using Create Query
using (IStatelessSession session = SessionManager.SessionFactory.OpenStatelessSession())
      {
IList<Employee> lstEmployee = session.CreateQuery("from Employee "). List<Employee>();               
return lstEmployees.ToList<Employee>();
   }

//Fetching Data using ADO.net
DataTable dtEmployees = /*Data is fetched from ADO.net using SQL Query*/;
        List<Employee> lstEmployee = new List<Employee>();

        foreach (DataRow dr in dtEmployees.AsEnumerable())
        {
            Employee employee = new Employee
            {
                ID = dr.Field<int>("ID"),
                Name = dr.Field<decimal>("Name"),
                DateOfJoin = dr.Field<int>("DateOfJoin"),
                DateOfBirth = dr.Field<int>("DateOfBirth"),
                DepartmentID = dr.Field<int>("DepartmentID"),
                Status = dr.Field<DateTime>("Status"),
            };
            lstEmployee.Add(Employee);
```

Comment: Are you factoring out the building of a session factory?  Also in your statement above you say NHibernate is actually faster (867 ms).

Comment: Are you sure you're measuring what you think you are measuring? The two queries you've shown are *exactly* the same (except for the field and table aliases), I fail to see how they could result in these kind of differences in execution time in a SQL profiler.

Comment: Also please state which version of NHibernate you are using.

Comment: Are you sure you want to fetch 75 000 rows in a single query? Also you are not showing the exact code paths that you are measuring. You should run the query at least few times. Then remove the slowest and fastest time and calculate average. Initializing static values etc. might take lot of time and those happen only the first time.

Comment: we are using NHibernate 3.1. Sorry I have now modified the timings.

Comment: @SumitKute You should post the exact code you are using to measure the performance. Just copy paste it from the source code. Or are those numbers from sql server profiler?

Answer (score 1):

the following copies the complete 75k results in a seperate list;

```
IList<Employee> lstEmployee = ...
return lstEmployees.ToList<Employee>();
```

it is enough to

```
return lstEmployees;
```